# Mini GBIC on 2 different brand switches?

Tags: networking

I have a 48 port TrendNet Gigabit switch, and a 48 port dlink gigabit switch. Both with Mini GBIC slots. If I purchase a Mini GBIC that is said to be compatible w/ both switches, could I actually "trunk", or connect rather, both switches with it? Or does that not work because they would be 2 different OS's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would work, the OS on each switch has nothing to do with the ability of each to talk with each other over the link layer.